# Excel Dynamic Range in formula

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to make the below formula work with a dynamic range.

```
=INDEX($B$3:$B$10000,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($F$3:$F$10000>0,0),))
```

The actual range I want to search would be `B23` to `B10000` and `F23` to `F10000`.

This formula is what would return the `23`:

```
=MATCH(TODAY(),B1:B10000,0)+1
```

I can't seem to get the syntax right to make them work together.

Answer (score 0):

Use `INDIRECT`. For example, to reference $F$23:$F$10000 you can use the expression:

```
INDIRECT("$F$"&MATCH(TODAY(),$B$1:$B$10000,0)+1&":$F$10000")
```

Comment: Indirect is volatile. `INDEX($F:$F,MATCH(TODAY(),B1:B10000,0)+1):$F$10000` would mean the same, but avoiding volatile INDIRECT.